# "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" Error on Bootstrap Page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to add carousels to my modals and I'm having an issue calling my JavaScript. I can't remember how to call the javascript file but I copy pasted what I found online. I'm not sure if that is the problem or its something with the code template I found. Thanks for the help.

Here's my code:

```js
/* copy loaded thumbnails into carousel */
$('.row .thumbnail').on('load', function() {
  
}).each(function(i) {
  if(this.complete) {
   var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    var itemDiv = $(this).parents('div');
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
    
    item.attr("title",title);
   $(itemDiv.html()).appendTo(item);
   item.appendTo('.carousel-inner'); 
    if (i==0){ // set first item active
     item.addClass('active');
    }
  }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval:false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
})

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.row .thumbnail').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
   var id = parseInt(idx);
   $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
   
});
```

```css
.modal-dialog {}
.thumbnail {margin-bottom:6px;}

.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
  background-image:none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head> 
  <script src="/js/myscripts.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 </head>

 <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Bootstrap 3 Lightbox using Modal</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 1" href="//placehold.it/1024x768"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 2" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/2255EE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 3" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 4" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 5" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/2255EE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 6" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 8" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/777"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 9" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 10" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/EEE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 11" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 12" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/DDD"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 13" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <a href="http://bootply.com/xmgGysNWgn">Edit on Bootply</a>
    <hr>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
  <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modaCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you did not include jQuery script.

Comment: You haven't even included jQuery. Include that before your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  issue with your code  is that you are missing all the external resources required for the bootstrap carousel

You need to add the below mentioned files.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Updated Snippet**

```js
/* copy loaded thumbnails into carousel */
$('.row .thumbnail').on('load', function() {
  
}).each(function(i) {
  if(this.complete) {
   var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    var itemDiv = $(this).parents('div');
    var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");
    
    item.attr("title",title);
   $(itemDiv.html()).appendTo(item);
   item.appendTo('.carousel-inner'); 
    if (i==0){ // set first item active
     item.addClass('active');
    }
  }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$(function(){
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval:false});
});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
})

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.row .thumbnail').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
   var id = parseInt(idx);
   $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
   
});
```

```css
.modal-dialog {}
.thumbnail {margin-bottom:6px;}

.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
  background-image:none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head> 
  <script src="/js/myscripts.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Bootstrap 3 Lightbox using Modal</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 1" href="//placehold.it/1024x768"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 2" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/2255EE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 3" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 4" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 5" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/2255EE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 6" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 8" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/777"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 9" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 10" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/EEE"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 11" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/449955/FFF"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 12" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/DDD"></a></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 13" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/600x350/992233"></a></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <a href="http://bootply.com/xmgGysNWgn">Edit on Bootply</a>
    <hr>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
  <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modaCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs, if jQuery script is not loaded or missing.